# using Shiny to visualize a 2x2 table with classification by a third variable

Tags: r, shiny

I'm creating a Shiny app to help students understand selection bias. The context is use of insecticide treated nets and malaria. The confounding variable is pre-treatment with chloroquine which can clear parasites and lead to cases being misclassified as controls.

The two panels below, A and B, show what I'd like to do dynamically. A slider centered on 0 would control the amount and direction of misclassification (grey fill with red outline). Move the slider >0, and the misclassification rate would be higher for controls who report using bed nets. Move in the other direction and the misclassification would favor non-users.

This is a programming question in my mind because I'm looking for a way to visualize this in Shiny. Here's a toy dataset that replicates the example in panel A.

```
df <- data.frame(control=c(rep(1, 24), rep(0, 24)),
                 bednet=(c(rep(1,18), rep(0,6),
                           rep(1, 12), rep(0, 12))),
                 chloro=(c(rep(0, 17), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
                           rep(NA, 24))))
```

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Where is the "misclassification rate"  values on the plot here?
And did you draw this or plot it?
Also, could you provide other snapshots of other stats?

Comment: `chloro` value of `1` is misclassifcation

Comment: sorry, only the first question came through on my phone initially. misclassification is among controls. grey fill with red outline. that corresponds to a value of `chloro==1` and `control==1`. i drew this in google slides and have not found a good way to plot yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ggplot2`  approach. I kept the separate mutate calls on purpose so you can explore the code stepwise.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(control=c(rep(1, 24), rep(0, 24)),
                 bednet=(c(rep(1,18), rep(0,6),
                           rep(1, 12), rep(0, 12))),
                 chloro=(c(rep(0, 17), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
                           rep(NA, 24))))
ncols <- 6

plot_data <- df %>%  
  mutate(misclass = ifelse(chloro == 1 & control == 1, 1, 0)) %>% 
  mutate(control = factor(control, c(0, 1), c("Cases","Controls"))) %>% 
  arrange(control, bednet, -misclass) %>% 
  group_by(control) %>% 
  mutate(col = rep(1:ncols, times = n()/ncols)) %>% 
  mutate(row = rep(1:4, each = ncols)) %>% 
  mutate(line = max(.$row[bednet == 0]) + 0.5) %>% 
  mutate(fill = case_when(misclass == 1 ~ "grey50",
                          misclass == 0 & control == "Cases" ~ "firebrick",
                          misclass == 0 & control == "Controls" ~ "grey50")) %>% 
  mutate(color = case_when(misclass == 1 ~ "firebrick",
                          misclass == 0 & control == "Cases" ~ "firebrick",
                          misclass == 0 & control == "Controls" ~ "grey50"))  %>% 
  mutate(divider = ifelse(control == "Cases", Inf, NA))


ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = col, y = row, fill = fill, color = color)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 4, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = line), show.legend = FALSE, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = divider)) +
  facet_wrap(~control) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  scale_color_identity() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

You can set the misclass conditions via `shiny` inputs, and then create `plot_data` as a reactive data frame.  You'd then follow the usual steps for plot outputs in `shiny`

Comment: exploring this now. looks awesome. is `arrange(control, bednet, -misclass)` removing `misclass`? I'm getting an error.

Comment: No, it's simply sorting it by descending order.  If you get an error on that try `arrange(control, bednet, desc(misclass))`.

Comment: Check your package versions, update if needed.  You can always omit that step, although the misclassified dots will not be in the order shown

Comment: OK, still checking. I get an error at the first `case_when` step. I just installed `tidyverse` (outing myself as late to the party), so should be up to date, I think.

Comment: This is what I get for using development versions of packages.  Try placing a `.$` in front of variable names in `case_when` statements.  e.g. `case_when(.$misclass == 1 ~ "grey50" ....`

Comment: no luck with `dplyr` version 0.5, but switching to the development version does the trick

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133487/discussion-between-jake-kaupp-and-eric-green).